# How to activate PointerReleased event for an UIElement inside a ScrollViewer in UWP app?

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have a `ScrollViewer` inside which there is a `Grid` in my UWP app. The `Grid` has some `TextBlocks` inside it and an `image` element. I want to be able to chage the source of the `image` element whenever there is a right or left swipe in the `Grid`. I used Pointer Manipulation events and my code is as follows

```
private void MiddleGrid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Y2 = e.GetCurrentPoint(MiddleGrid).Position.Y;
       X2 = e.GetCurrentPoint(MiddleGrid).Position.X;

       if (Math.Abs(Y2 - Y1) < 60)
       {
           if (X2 - X1 > 40)
           {
               PreviousImage();
           }
           if (X1 - X2 > 40)
           {
               NextImage();
           }
       }

   }

   private void MiddleGrid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
   {

       ((Grid)sender).CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
       Y1 = e.GetCurrentPoint(MiddleGrid).Position.Y;
       X1 = e.GetCurrentPoint(MiddleGrid).Position.X;

   }
```

but since the Grid is enclosed inside a ScrollViewer only the PointerPressed event gets fired. How do I make the PointerReleased event to be activated? I even tried the following in my Page_Loaded event

```
MiddleGrid.PointerPressed += MiddleGrid_PointerPressed;
        this.AddHandler(PointerReleasedEvent,new PointerEventHandler(MiddleGrid_PointerReleased),true);
```

I cannot change the whole layout of my app as it will make it less intuitive.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I creat the xaml as you described. When I  release click the PointerReleased event works well. So please post the XAML code.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention this. It works well in my PC and mouse. It doesn't work only when I run the app in my mobile and the input is touch.

Comment: Try setting the [`HorizontalScrollMode` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollmode.aspx) to `Disabled`

Comment: Does your `ScrollViewer` scroll only vertically?